# How to route to a controller when controller is not recognized in first place in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, api, routes

I'm trying to create a API broker program so that a frontend can call a api with any endpoint given, in the broker I decide which URL to be executed. I have the following problem:

In my front-end I am calling my API broker with the following url:

*http://localhost:54857/getClients*

When my API Broker receives this request it instantly returns a error, before this error occurs I want to redirect this to a controller action which does not match the name *getClients*.

**Front-end** code which requests the call to my API Broker:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:54857/";
        string operation = "getClients";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //get logged in userID
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string sessionID = context.Session["userID"].ToString();

            //Create request and add headers
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Custom header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("loggedInUser", sessionID);

            //Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(operation);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My **routing** in my API Broker:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller=Redirect}/{action=RedirectApi}/{id}");
    }
```

**API Broker controller:**

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public Customer RedirectApi()
    {
        Customer t = dbProducts.Customers
            .Where(h => h.customerID == 1)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return t;
    }
```

I also have a filter that works when the api method *getClients* is present:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Checks if header is method Get and has attribute
        if ((actionContext.Request.Method.Method == "GET") && (actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("loggedinUser").First() != null))
        {

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
```

In the current situation(code above) I'm receiving a error and the code in my API broker is not even getting executed. What I'm trying to achieve is that I redirect any given request received in my API Broker to my API Broker Controller which executed the method *RedirectApi()*.

Hope somebody can help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: A filter isn’t invoked, if your routing doesn’t succeed. A middleware could do the job, but it has to be at the very start of the middleware-channel.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it just does not execute the API Broker controller so the data im trying to receive is undefinied.

Comment: So you get a 404 Status-Code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this code after the other mapping code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"404-PageNotFound",
"{*url}",
new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectApi" }
);
```